# Transfer fund to stripe connected account

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I have an application where I take payment from the customer and transfer it to the payer but as a divided installment how can I do this in stripe because the when is setup payment intent it transfers the payment directly to the buyer so how I take the full amount the transfer it to the connected account without extra fees

Comment: You can take a look at https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers 
It will be two steps. 1. Create payment WITHOUT the stripe_account header, step 2: create a transfer to the connected account